# HTML Canvas Zoom-in

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am designing a very basic animation with a few circles moving around in a HTML5 canvas.
I'm currently using the jCanvaScript library to make it simplier (I need to group different shapes together and animate them synchronously)

I need to be able to zoom in and out and to move around inside the canvas.
I've seen many libraries (including the jCanvaScript) they all have a .scale() and .translate() function which allow to transform one of the shapes in the canvas but what I need is a global one, that acts on all the shapes inside the canvas. And really it seems that no library provides this...

The ideal solution would be kind of a setViewPoint(x,y,width,height) function like in the Raphaël.js library.

Do you know how I could achieve this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look on this :
 `http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-select-shapes-by-name-with-kineticjs/`
hopefully  kineticjs will help you.